# How to fix AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click' in insta bot

Tags: python, selenium

**after running the code bellow i am getting the

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'.

pleas some one help me to fix this**

rest is the code:->

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

import random

import time

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



def sleep_for_period_of_time():
    

     limit = random.randint(7,10)
    
     time.sleep(limit)

user = input("Enter your username: ")

pwd = input("Enter your password: ")

def main():
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    
    options.add_argument("--lang=en")
    
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    
    browser.get("https://www.instagram.com")
    
    time.sleep(5)

    username_input = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='username']")
    password_input = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='password']")

    username_input.send_keys(user)
    password_input.send_keys(pwd)
    sleep_for_period_of_time()

    login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
    login_button.click()
    sleep_for_period_of_time()

    not_now = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='cmbtv']/button")
    not_now.click()
    sleep_for_period_of_time()

    page_ig = input("Enter page username: ")
    browser.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/{page_ig}")
    sleep_for_period_of_time()

    followers_link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//ul/li[2]/a")
    followers_link.click()
    sleep_for_period_of_time()

    num_follow = input("How many person you want to follow: ")

    while(True):
        try:
            i = 0
            list_of_followers = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button/div/div[contains(text(), "Follow")]')
            for person in list_of_followers:
                if person.text == "Follow":
                    person.click()
                    print("Followed!")
                    i +=1
                    print(i)
                    sleep_for_period_of_time()
                else:
                    pass
                if i >= int(num_follow):
                    break

            browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", list_of_followers[i])

            answer = input("The programm finished! Click on 'e' to exit.. ")
            if answer.lower().startswith("e"):
                browser.quit()
                exit()

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Heading

complete error is:->

```
  D:\Users\singh\PycharmProjects\IG-Bot-main\fuf.py:21: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\singh\PycharmProjects\IG-Bot-main\fuf.py", line 77, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Users\singh\PycharmProjects\IG-Bot-main\fuf.py", line 33, in main
    login_button.click()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that

```
login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
```

Is not finding a button object. My guess is either your xpath find element is incorrect, or `sleep_for_period_of_time()` is not sleeping for long enough. You could try something like this

```
login_button = None
while not login_button:
    sleep_for_period_of_time()
    login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
```

So that you will never try to click a button that has not yet been found.

Answer (score 0):

**Error:**  *AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'*

This error can be caused by either the button type mentioned here is not found **(OR)** Due to missing allow cookies accept button click, before redirecting to login. **(OR)** the button might disabled

**If the button is disabled, Try:**

```
    login_button = browser.find_element("xpath","//button[@class='sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     ']")

    # try removing the attribute.
    browser.execute_script('arguments[0].removeAttribute("disabled");', login_button)
    login_button.click()
```

So, After Calling the browser.get(), Find cookies accept button class and click on it, which can redirect to the login button.

**If cookies are opened before clicking login:**

```
    cookie = browser.find_element("xpath","//button[@class='aOOlW  bIiDR  ']") 
    cookie.click()
```

And as per selenium 4.3.0 , the method **find_element_by_xpath** has been depricated.